# Why .getjson doesnt work but .ajax does?

Tags: javascript, html, json, ajax

I'm working on Free Code Camp's wiki viewer and trying to figure out the api call. I thought getjson and ajax were equivalent but maybe i'm doing something wrong.

So at first I  used this getjson code:

```
$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=' + search, 
function(api){
    console.log(api);
}, 'jsonp');
```

but it returned this error: `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.`

Then I used ajax with the same url:

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&format=json&srsearch=' + search,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: getWiki //just console logs the api
            });
```

and this seemed to return the api call. Can anyone explain why getjson didnt work but ajax did?

Comment: What's with that space... `api.php?  action=`?

Comment: Because jsonp !== json

Comment: theres no space in actual code. I accidentally put that there when formatting this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the required `callback=?` query parameter to force `$.getJSON` to perform a JSONP request

```
$.getJSON('http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?callback=?', {
  action: 'query',
  list: 'search',
  format: 'json',
  srsearch: search
}, api => {
  // response handler
})
```

See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/#jsonp

Comment: ah, I wasn't aware of that requirement. Thanks! Both work now

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution also I left an alternative using only **JavaScript**

**NOTE** I added this `&origin=*` param in the url to make it work using this the original jQuery code.

```js
var search = 'php';
var searchURL = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&generator=search&origin=*&gsrsearch=' + search;

// Using JSON
$.getJSON(searchURL, function(data){
    var read = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log('Using jQuery: ' + read);
}, 'jsonp');

// Using JavaScript
var getJSON = function(url, callback) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url, true);
  xhr.responseType = 'json';
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var status = xhr.status;
    if (status == 200) {
      callback(null, xhr.response);
    } else {
      callback(status);
    }
  };
  xhr.send();
};

getJSON(searchURL, function(err, data) {
  if (err != null) {
    alert('Something went wrong: ' + err);
  } else {
    var read = JSON.stringify(data);
    console.log('Using JavaScript: ', read);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You are correct, sorry. I'd suggest adding a hint about the added origin param that made it work

Comment: Thank you is a nice suggestion.